Distance of consecutive terms of a sequence goes to zero implies convergence in functional spaces.
Consider the vector space of real bounded functions $\Delta =$ {$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}:  \text{ f is bounded}$}.
Then the following is a norm on $\Delta$:
$$\left\| f \right\|_{\infty}=\underset{x\in\mathbb{R}}{sup}|f(x)|$$
In fact, $(\Delta,\left\| \cdot \right\|_{\infty})$ is a Banach space (real normed complete vector space). Consider a sequence $f_n$ in $\Delta$ such that:
$$\left\| f_n-f_{n-1} \right\|_{\infty}\underset{n}{\longrightarrow }0$$
Then we know that {$f_n$} is not necessarily a Cauchy sequence, hence it does not necessarily converge.
The question is: is there a (functional) complete vector space $A \subseteq $ {$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$} with a norm $|\cdot |$ such that if {$f_n$} is a sequence in $A$ them the following two conditions hold:

if $| f_n-f_{n-1}|\underset{n}{\longrightarrow }0$ then $f_n$ is Cauchy, that is, converges to a limit $f$.
if $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $(A, | \cdot |)$ then $f_n\to f$ point-wise (or at least almost everywhere convergence.).

Thank you

If you require that $A$ is a (non-trivial) vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, then no norm such that $\|f_n - f_{n-1}\| \to 0$ implies Cauchy. Consider the following generic example.
Let $a_0$ be any non-zero element in the vector space. We recursively define $a_n$ as follows:
$$ a_n = a_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}a_0 $$
Note it is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, so multiplication by $1/n$ and addition are valid, and $a_n$ is in the vector space.
Then we see that
$$ \|a_n - a_{n-1}\| = \left\|\frac{1}{n} a_{0}\right\| $$
Which goes to $0$.
However,
$$\|a_n\| = \left\|a_0 + a_0\left(1+\frac{1}{2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right\| = \|a_0\|\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\right) $$
This diverges, hence the sequence cannot converge.

You forgot to assume that $a_0\neq 0$

Ah yes! Thank you, shall make the edit

Thanks for the nice answer
